# Visual Studio 2010 to 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2010, migration, visual-studio-2017

I developed a VC++ project using Visual Studio 2010.  I have to maintain compatibility with VS2010 due to a customer requirement.  I bought a new PC that has Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2017 is the only version that will run on Windows 10.  So I installed VS 2017 on my Windows 10 machine, and copied my source code to my new computer.  The project opens fine, but there are 100s of build errors.  The last error is shown below:

Error   MSB8020 The build tools for Visual Studio 2010 (Platform Toolset = 'v100') cannot be found. To build using the v100 build tools, please install Visual Studio 2010 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution"....

I checked Microsoft's website and Visual Studio 2010 Platform Toolset is not compatible with Windows 10.  I do not understand the implications of the second suggested solution "upgrade to the current VS tools.." as I have to be able to build the code that is developed on my Windows 10 machine on a computer that has VS 2010.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Toolset with Xp support, but it's not the same. Otherwise Toolset Vs2010 is not compatible with VS17. You could install a VM with windows 7/vista and install VS2010 on the VM.